# A jasmine spec has timed out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, protractor

We are trying to test a React component that has "Navigation Enforcement" on it using Protractor. The idea is to enforce a sequential flow- disallowing users to use the url bar to navigate further than they've progressed naturally through the app.

The functionality works fine and these tests pass on some machines but gives a "Jasmine spec has timed out" error on others. Neither of these tests pass if we comment out the other, so we aren't able to narrow it down any further.

Is there something wrong with these two tests that we just aren't aware of?

```html
describe('Given navigation enforcer-wrapped component selectVehicle', () => {
    let until = protractor.ExpectedConditions
    beforeAll(() => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
    })

    describe('When a user attempts to navigate to a previous component', () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
            browser.get('/#/verifyInformation')
            browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.id('verify-information-container'))), 3000, 'Verify Information not loading')
        })

        it('Then they successfully navigate to the requested route', () => {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + '/#/verifyInformation')
        })

        afterAll(() => {
            browser.get('/#/vehicleSelection')
        })
    })

    describe('When a user attempts to navigate to a step BEYOND where they have progressed in the app', () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
            browser.get('/#/damages')
            browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.id('select-vehicle-container'))), 3000, 'vehicleSelection not loading')
        })

        it('Then they NOT brought to their requested route and are instead redirected to their current page', () => {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + '/#/vehicleSelection')
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: could you share error text?

Comment: Unfortunately it hits that test and all it will say is "A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow." over and over as it tries to rerun it.

Comment: my main advice for you - disable Control Flow. It is deprecated. Take a look at official Protractor site.

Comment: One machine is likely just slower than the other. First thing I would try is increasing the jasmine default timeout interval.

Comment: I agree with @tehbeardedone, Just increase defaultJasmineTime in conf file & check the execution.